# Extracting individual responses from Google Forms using an API

Tags: google-forms, google-api

So I have an old account where I can see all the individual responses since I am the owner of the forms. However, a few weeks ago, my account got disabled and I am unable to recover it. Luckily, as a different user, I am able to view previous responses from other people, but I am unable to view them individually. I am really desperate to get the individual responses so I try to find all the ways to do this and my only option I could think of is to somehow extract the responses. I searched up ways to extract responses and I found that using Google API might work. Unfortunately, I am very inexperienced on using Google API so I don't exactly know what I am doing. Is there a way that I am able to use Google API to extract the form responses individually or is there another method that can be done?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/forms, then choose one tool, Apps Script or the Forms API. Questions about the Forms API are off-topic here, but might be on-topic on [so]. If you need further help, please provide more details i.e. if you are able to open the form on edit mode or if you have access a spreadsheet linked to the form.

Comment: I don't have edit access to the forms and there no spreadsheets linked to the form.